# Want to store html codes in DB, And let it appear when you click a button

Tags: python, html, jquery, flask

I'm wondering how to store and load html codes. Especifically, I wanna store html codes in some database, and let it appear on the screen when you click a button.

I'm now trying to store it in csv file, and it seems not working. Don't know other ways.

This is what i've been doing, and you would know what I wanna do.

--csv--(opened and rendered as 'obj' in flask)

```
ind, title, article
1, A, <p> content</p>
2, B, <table style="color:blue"><tr>a</tr><table>
```

--html --(FLASK)

```
<div id='content'><div>
<tr id={{obj.ind}}>
    <td>{{ obj.ind }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.title }}</td>
        <script type=text/javascript>
          $(document).ready(function(){             
                $("#{{obj.ind}}").click(function(){
                    $('#content').html("{{ obj.article }}") 

                })
            })      

        </script>    
    </td>
```

There's a python Flask code sheet hidden, which open csv file as 'obj', and render it with html sheet.

As you click td 'title', the 'content' div must shows each html contents.
But it doesn't work. I think the csv file can't store html codes, but don't know other alternatives.
Hope you know the way.

Comment: What do you see in the generated source sent to browser? Any errors in browser dev tools console?

Comment: @charlietfl it shows html code itself, but as a text.
like this [ <div style="position:fixed; top: 100px; left:350px; width:300px; word-wrap:break-word" id="content"><table style="color:blue"><tr>a</tr><table></div> ]

Comment: @charlietfl  in this console,  '<table style="color:blue"><tr>a</tr><table>' this part's color apeares in black, just as saying it's pure text, not a code.
 Moreover,  as I copy and paste this part, this is parsed in another way. like this.
 <div style="position:fixed; top: 100px; left:350px; width:300px; word-wrap:break-word" id="content">&lt;table style="color:blue"&gt;&lt;tr&gt;a&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;table&gt;</div>

Comment: Looks like back end is converting `<` and `>` to html entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: @charlietfl what should I do? it's of no use decoding with html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

charlietfl is right.
The html code is automatically escaped.
To prevent this, you could use the jinja filter [safe](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#safe).

`{{ obj.article | safe }}`

Pay attention to quotation marks inside your replacement.